# Multiple regression on hedge fund returns

Tags: risk-management, regression, factor-models

I have a data set of long/short equity hedge funds returns and their associated benchmarks (market indices). I need to form multiple regression on the fund returns using the benchmarks returns as independent variables (i am allowed to form linear combination or manipulation of the indices or even non-linear combinations). Of course, I do not know which independent variables to choose. Are techniques such as subset selection, Lasso, and Ridge supposed to be used in situation like this?

Comment: Can I ask, is this for a professional or academic project? Also, are you restricted to only using fund returns as your independent variables?

Comment: From your own question, it sounds like you are being asked to regress the hedge fund returns (dependent variable) against the benchmarks (independent variables).  It further sounds like you can use ordinary least squares, and/or some using some non-linear function and/or transform your variable such that you can use OLS.

Comment: @DavidAddison Hi David. Good to see you again. I would say it is a professional project. Well, fund returns are 'dependent' variables and their indices should be independent variables.

Comment: @AlRacoon Hi AIRacoon, you are correct. I am asked to regress the hedge fund returns (DV) against indices returns (IV). I can use OLS and/or some using non-linear function and/or transform my variable such that I can use OLS. You are right. From my understanding, there have been many academic studies where they regress hedge fund returns (dependent variables) against market variables such as S&P500, Treasury yield spread, credit spread, etc. (independent variables) but not against only benchmarks and their combinations/manipulations.

Comment: @JunJang. My only thought is that it depends on what you're trying to do. If it were me, and I was trying to simply "describe" each fund's style through its exposure to various international benchmarks, then any number curve fitting techniques may work. If, however, I was to trying to "predict" the funds' returns, then I would inform my supervisor that this is not possible with the data given.

Comment: @DavidAddison Thank you for your reply. I agree that any number curve fitting techniques may work for "describing" the funds' return. However, why wouldn't they be good for "predicting"? Say my dependent variable is Fund 1, and independent variable is S&P500 index and the coefficient is 0.5. Wouldn't it predict that as the return on S&P500 index go up by 1 percent, the return on the Fund 1 goes up by 0.50%? Is it going back to what we discussed above? (long only indices are not good benchmarks for long short equity funds)

Comment: @JunJang That's what my intuition tells me, but I haven't seen the data. If correlations are low across the board for the funds and their indices, then I would surmize that any "risk adjusted return" model based on those indices would almost certainly be spurious. If, however, there correlations are robust, then I would feel more comfortable with an 
"alpha" factor model to estimate each fund's risk-adjusted return. And since this model is presumably going to be implemented in the real world, I would think that robustness of the estimates would be at the forefront of the PM's mind.

Comment: For the record, it looks my intuitions about correlations were wrong. More and more, long short equity managers are becoming closet indexers. http://www.calamos.com/fundinvestor/MarketInsights/investmentideas/article?name=how-long-short-funds-correlate-to-the-sp500

Comment: @DavidAddison Hmm. So if long/short equity funds are indeed highly correlated with indices, should I go about making some changes to the Task 1 too? Or should I keep them as it is now? (I implemented three scenarios there. 1. normal efficient frontier, 2. simulating multivariate lognormal, and 3. use MSCI ACWI as benchmark and form tracking error efficient frontier)

Comment: @DavidAddison I just calculated R^2 for each of the fund regressed on their associated benchmark. The average of those 20 R^2 was about 0.40 and some were as close as 0.90.

Comment: Let's continue in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72969/how-to-choose-a-portfolio-from-the-efficient-frontier

Comment: @DavidAddison Hi David! Hope you are doing well. Are you still there?